# Sublime Text 3 , can't find SFTP in package manager

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I managed to install the package manger in Sublime Text 3 on OSX. When I go to add a package to it, I don't see SFTP as an option.

I did this on my Windows machine not long ago and everything went smoothly.

Am I missing something? Any reason SFTP couldn't show up as an option in the package manager to install?

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is, is it already installed (and/or possibly in the list of `ignored_packages`)? For example if you copied some of the configuration from your windows machine to the OSX machine, Package Control may have already installed it for you. Also, do you see any errors in the console when you display the package list?

Comment: This is on a fresh install (but maybe it's under the ignored_packages? Where can that be found? Thanks

Comment: I also tried removing everything in /Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3. The contents from that folder just come back when I relaunch Sublime